# Are there any public real-life code examples of ML applications in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, applications

Problems I often face at work usually differ from tutorial or book-like examples so I end up with a code that works but it's not elegant and takes too much time to write.

I wanted to ask you if there are some publicly accesible examples or repositories of Python codes that deal with machine learning development and application process but were created in a real company or organisation to develop their real-life products or services?

EDIT: What I do not think about are libraries or packages repositories such as tensorflow. I would like to see some codes of projects that for example use tensorflow to create some other product or service.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but likely to be a very rare result, since any code that gives a company a commercial edge directly on a core task is likley to remain private and proprietary. I'm assuming you will not want to include e.g. TensorFlow or other frameworks published by the big tech companies? These could be interpreted to meet your criteria in theory. For instance Google really does use TensforFlow internally, that's the reason it has so many options for deployment. However, they don't generally make full code for their services that *use* TF models public.

Comment: Yes, tensorflow is pretty close to what I need, but in this question I wanted to ask about some code examples that for example already use packages like tensorflow to pursue other tasks.

Comment: Maybe some non-profit working projects?

Comment: If you are not looking for something like TF, edit your post to clarify what you are exactly looking for. In general, you should try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to Google it with "[org name] tensorflow github" and look what you get.

For instance I found:

[Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn)

[Nvidia](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow-determinism)

[Intel](https://github.com/tensorflow/ngraph-bridge)

Answer (score 1):

If you search [Papers with Code](https://paperswithcode.com/) for [`python "machine learning"`](https://paperswithcode.com/search?q_meta=&q=python+%22machine+learning%22) (or a more specific query) you will get numerous results. Note these will be mostly scientific applications or methods.

Comment: Not what I really wanted. Youre talking about libraries such as tf or pytorch just different, and I meant projects that use such libraries for some practical real life application on some real data set.

Answer (score 0):

Find some opensource projects like [Arxiv sanity](https://github.com/karpathy/arxiv-sanity-preserver) by andrej karpathy which finds ML related papers from arxiv.org. You can find similar opensource applications.